# Svg image not showing in flutter

Tags: flutter

`SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/close_icon.svg', color: Colors.white,)`

not showing image. output **error** is

The following StateError was thrown resolving a single-frame picture stream:

Bad state: Could not parse "currentColor" as a color.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can open your svg asset `assets/images/close_icon.svg` and edit color property from currentColor to any other valid color (like black or white).

Comment: it worked in my project. @francis_m

Answer (score 5):

[image]

First open your svg image and try this instead of `stroke="currentColor"` to `stroke="black"`

Answer (score 2):

```
const svg = 'assets/logo.svg';
```

// If want to show orginal svg color use this

```
SvgPicture.asset(svg, 
   semanticsLabel: 'My SVG Picture' 
);
```

// If want to change the color use color properties

```
SvgPicture.asset(svg, 
   color: Colors.black, 
   semanticsLabel: 'My SVG Picture' 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my cas not just use `svgPicture.assets()` in `Scaffold`

I have to announce

```
final Widget mySvg = SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/24/my.svg');
```

before `return Scaffold` and use

```
child: SizedBox(
   width: 24,
   height: 24,
)
```